# toctree maxdepth for display but not for navigation sidebar

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, restructuredtext, toctree

I would like to use something like this in the root index:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   sub1/index
   sub2/index
```

So only the top-level titles are shown.

But this also limits the navigation sidebar. Can this be avoided somehow?

---

I also found [:tocdepth:](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.2/markup/misc.html?highlight=tocdepth). So I tried:

```
:tocdepth: 1

.. toctree::

   sub1/index
   sub2/index
```

But strangely this does not seem to have an effect at all. There is not limit to the depth of the tree displayed.

Comment: Have you tried adding `:tocdepth:` to the _content_ files (such as `sub/index.rst`), instead of the _table-of-contents_ file?

Comment: I tried various combinations but none seem to give the expected result.

Comment: Sphinx issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7171